# Strong parameter params.require with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I tried to use link_to on Assignment/show.html.erb to create a Bid.

The show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Create Bid", bids_path(:status => "Pending", :assignment_id => @assignment.id, :user_id => current_user.id), :method => :post %>
```

In the bids_controller.rb this line of code didn't work:

```
params.require(:bid).permit(:status, :assignment_id, :user_id)
```

I had to change it to the following to get it to work:

```
params.permit(:status, :assignment_id, :user_id)
```

I don't really understand the problem but I think that if I didn't include the params.require part my code won't be as secured from attacks or problems in future.

Anyway, I'd like to include the params.require part of the code and I hope someone will be able to guide me on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: You have to show the entirety of the code including your relatoions - if assigment id and user id are passed through the link they might not need to be in the permit.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But I'd like to know the proper syntax to do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

params.require(:bid).permit(:status, :assignment_id, :user_id) means the params passing in would have the following structure

```
bid: {
  status: '',
  assignment_id: 1,
  user_id: 1
}
```

Therefore to construct a link_to tag that conforms to the structure of what you intended in strong parameters, you could try the example below

```
<%= link_to "Create Bid", bids_path(bid: {status: "Pending", assignment_id: @assignment.id, user_id:current_user.id}), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: I did as you asked and it worked! However, this line of code doesn't work now:

`if Bid.exists?(user_id: params[:user_id], assignment_id: params[:assignment_id])`

Comment: And may I know what does your suggested code means? Is it like defining an object called bid? @KennyChan

Comment: Okay I think I solved the problem by changing the code to 

`if Bid.exists?(user_id: params[:bid][:user_id], assignment_id: params[:bid][:assignment_id])`

Comment: Sorry was away, just saw your message, yup you would need to place [:bid] in front to reference it. Cheers